# Typescript type inference - Object key seen as unknown

Tags: typescript, object, type-inference

I want to make type inference from a `props` object given to a component then passed to a render. Object keys are correctly retrieved but all type are typed as `unknown`.
Need help to understand what's wrong in my types.

import React, { ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react'

```
type RenderPropsType = {
    isSubmitted: boolean
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type PropsType<
    O extends object,
    K extends keyof O,
    V extends ValueOf<O>
> = Record<K, V>

const FormWrapper = <
    O extends object,
    K extends keyof O,
    V extends ValueOf<O>
>({
    render,
    props,
    validationSchema,
}: {
    render: (props: PropsType<O, K, V>, formprops: RenderPropsType) => React.ReactNode
    // props: Partial<Record<K, (typeof props)[K]>>
    props: PropsType<O, K, V>
    validationSchema: any
}) => {

    const RenderProps = {
        isSubmitted: false,
    }

    return (
        <form>
            {render?.(props, { ...RenderProps })}
        </form>
    )
}
type propType = {inactivity: boolean}
const props: propType = { inactivity: false };

<FormWrapper
    props={props}
    validationSchema={null}
    render={(props, formprops) => {
        return (
            <>{props?.inactivity}</>
        )}}></FormWrapper>
```

[Here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgK4DOSAogGb1IZwC%20c9UEIcA5FARi8AUMJgBPMEnwA7MlAAKXMFQAqk6QF5cwuHrjAqAZQoAjEMBgwkJAFxxTECABtUM4a1ESpcAGopnCiQAeXoAHlUAPjhtVQBtAGskcQh6OFUAXTENOCUIFXUpMN19YLgkAA9rOSo4CFMAK2YsEr0AaXKqpBq4JJS04MxWv07qklr-QJDw4MjhaO1kNGgSMLbsXznhZZkqeAAxaBAAdSgUMCkoGLhi-TgyyrHa%20qaMIbuOx%207x3uTU%20-e%20l8o2%20EwCQVCYVm8wAFDhhgI5EgoIC9GBlFRUXAAG4BYAkFAwYAQGRGNAACyQIBQQ1Y9nhd0R8nsMPR%20So9jyBQ0UOw6z8kWw9CObJU9mQSMUGMKSAAlDFosh0DAAHRKoikJDDAD02rgoo5uRQsGAATCSxWa2wMO8SH%20BtlcTaGUiczuBs50p5gzg-M2w1xznxhOJpIpVJQ9hQMnEHnlmmi8OGOz2snkXNq2gZd30hhM5ks1jsHACNCxngRSBgFCgMjgMOGdzCwqgIDdOY7OCZyIA-CrWRjsHgVSOJemMWxZZ4O3owtqW23hrKPNkfKKZdccMAZMrgNjLOJ7I4XG5PCn4B79coN1mDDuMHuD-Z6KXpKwANyiMKHVunc6XYYDU0HADWnfRA2DIkSTJSlqWAmQKGcZwwL0bsoGAgd2SFEUMXjRNG30ARq1resCI7MJIhAjE%2023Xd9wkVg53bDsp1YSI5x-E4zguZFIiAA)

Comment: Not sure why you need three generic arguments. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3M1m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes.. cant believe i was so dumb for searching complicated way of doing that while the solution was so simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need that many generic arguments. In fact, your arguments are used to re-create the initial object, so I can just use one generic argument for the whole props:

```
const FormWrapper = <
   T extends object,
>({
    render,
    props,
}: {
    render: (props: T, formprops: RenderPropsType) => React.ReactNode
    props: T
    validationSchema: any
}) => {
  return null;
}
```

Testing:

```
type propType = { inactivity: boolean }
const props: propType = { inactivity: false };

<FormWrapper
    props={props}
    validationSchema={null}
    render={(props, formprops) => { // propType
        return (
            <>{props?.inactivity}</>
        )
    }}></FormWrapper>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)